# How to group a data frame based on pre-specified column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data that looks like this:

```
 library(zoo)
 dt <- read.csv("http://dpaste.com/1612639/plain/",header=FALSE,fill=FALSE,na.strings = "")
 dt <- na.locf(dt)


> dt
   V1  V2                V3                V4       V5
1 FOO yyy Unigene126925_All Unigene137063_All 0.238087
2 FOO yyy Unigene126925_All  Unigene24551_All 0.374231
3 FOO yyy Unigene126925_All  Unigene31835_All 0.367897
4 BAR xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene165366_All 0.247844
5 BAR xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene111784_All 0.344493
```

What I want to do is to group them based on V1, the content of each group is  a data-frame with values from V3 up to V5 of the above.
It looks like this:

Group FOO

```
     V1               V2                V3             
1 Unigene126925_All Unigene137063_All 0.238087
2 Unigene126925_All  Unigene24551_All 0.374231
3 Unigene126925_All  Unigene31835_All 0.367897
```

Group BAR

```
   V1               V2                V3   
1 Unigene126925_All Unigene165366_All 0.247844
2 Unigene126925_All Unigene111784_All 0.344493
```

How can I achieve that in R?
Later for each group I will apply some function to its data frame.

Comment: There are heaps of function in `base` R, `data.table`, `plyr` et c where you can apply functions on grouped data, without _explicitly_ splitting it into separate data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split`:

```
> split(dt[, 3:5], dt$V1)
$BAR
                 V3                V4       V5
4 Unigene126925_All Unigene165366_All 0.247844
5 Unigene126925_All Unigene111784_All 0.344493

$FOO
                 V3                V4       V5
1 Unigene126925_All Unigene137063_All 0.238087
2 Unigene126925_All  Unigene24551_All 0.374231
3 Unigene126925_All  Unigene31835_All 0.367897
```

You may now run some function over this list and combine the results back with `unsplit`.

Answer (score 3):

Use dplyr, it's very intuitive.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %.%
 group_by(V1) %.%
 summarise(newvar = function))
```

Where function is the function you want to apply, e.g. `newvar = sum(V5)`

Answer (score 1):

if I recall correctly (and you might want slice the first arguments to the columns you need as well, e.g. dropping "V1"):

```
split(dt, dt$V1)
```